# Definable subsets of the J-hierarchy in fine structure theory

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory

So there is a lemma in Ralf Schindler's book, which is said to be an immediate consequence of a previous lemma, but it is not really immediate to me. So let me give some context.

Let $E$ be a set or a proper class. We say a function or relation is $\text{rud}_E,$ if it is rudimentary in $E$. And for any transitive set $U$, $\text{rud}_E(U)$ denotes the closure of $U$ under $\text{rud}_E$ functions. And for a structure $(U, \in, E)$,  $\tilde{\Sigma}_n^{(U, \in, E)}$ denotes the set of $\Sigma_n$-definable relations with parameters from $U$ and $\tilde{\Sigma}_\omega^{(U, \in, E)} = \bigcup_{n\in\omega}\tilde{\Sigma}_n^{(U, \in, E)}$. Also we index the J-hierarchy with limit ordinals. 
And the following is the lemma which we will quote:

> $(*)$ Let $U$ be a transitive set and $E \subseteq U$. Then $P(U)\cap\text{rud}_E(U\cup\{U\}) = P(U)\cap\tilde{\Sigma}_\omega^{(U, \in, E)}$.

And below is the lemma which is said to be a direct consequence of $(*)$:

> Let $E$ be a set or a proper class. Assume that $E \subseteq Lim \times V$, where $Lim$ is the class of all limit ordinals. Let us write $E_\alpha = \{x: (\alpha, x) \in E\}$ and $E|\alpha = E \cap (\alpha \times V)$ for limit ordinals $\alpha$. Let assume that $E_\alpha \subseteq J_\alpha[E]$ and that $(J_\alpha[E], \in, E_\alpha)$ is amenable for every limit ordinal $\alpha$. Then 
>   $$P(J_\alpha[E])\cap J_{\alpha + \omega}[E] = P(J_\alpha[E])\cap\tilde{\Sigma}_\omega^{(J_\alpha[E], \in, E|\alpha, E_\alpha)}.$$

So proving that the lhs is a subset of the rhs is not that hard because of the lemma, since $E\cap J_\alpha[E] = E|\alpha$. What I can't prove, is the converse and it's because of the $E_\alpha$ predicate. The best thing I tried was to modify the proof of $(*)$, but there I had to show that membership in $E_\alpha$ was $\text{rud}_E$, which isn't really clear to me.

So I looked this up in the handbook of set theory, there the equivalent result was mentioned, without this $E_\alpha$ predicate. To me, the thing that seems to be the main obstacle, is that there is no clear connection between $E \cap J_\alpha[E]$ and $E_\alpha$. And that we have less information to work with, in the structure $(J_\alpha[E], \in, E)$.

I hope someone can clarify the situation and tell me how this lemma is proven.

Comment: When posting such a question, you might want to point out that you index the $J$-hierachy by limit ordinals. It is quite common as well to index it with all ordinals (i.e. the next step after $J_\alpha[E]$ is $J_{\alpha+1}[E]$ instead of $J_{\alpha+\omega}[E]$).

Comment: @AndreasLietz, Oh you are right. I will edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we can strenghen $(\ast)$ a bit in the following sense: If $F$ satisfies the same assumption as $E$ then $$\mathcal P(U)\cap\operatorname{rud}_{E, F}(U\cup\{U\})=\mathcal P(U)\cap\bar\Sigma_\omega^{(U, \in, E, F)}$$
where $\operatorname{rud}_{E, F}$ closes under functions that are rudimentary in $E$ or $F$.

You can see that even with this relaxed assumption we cannot immediately apply $(\ast)$ to calculate $\mathcal P(J_{\alpha}[E])\cap J_{\alpha+\omega}[E]$ as elements of the form $(\alpha, x)\in E$ are not in $J_\alpha[E]$. This is why we need to consider $E_\alpha$. The following holds true:
$$\mathcal P(J_\alpha[E])\cap J_{\alpha+\omega}[E]=\mathcal P(J_\alpha[E])\cap\operatorname{rud}_{E|\alpha, E_\alpha}(J_\alpha[E]\cup\{J_\alpha[E]\})=\mathcal P(J_\alpha[E])\cap\bar\Sigma_\omega^{(J_\alpha[E],\in, E|\alpha, E_\alpha)}$$
The second equality is true by the revised version of $(\ast)$ above, noting that $E_\alpha\subseteq J_\alpha[E]$. For the first equality we simply observe that $$J_{\alpha+\omega}[E]=\operatorname{rud}_E(J_\alpha[E]\cup\{J_\alpha[E]\})=\operatorname{rud}_{E|\alpha+1}(J_\alpha[E]\cup\{J_\alpha[E]\})=\operatorname{rud}_{E|\alpha, E_\alpha}(J_\alpha[E]\cup\{J_\alpha[E]\})$$
Here the first equality is by definition, the second one holds as in general 
$$\operatorname{rud}_E(U\cup\{U\})=\operatorname{rud}_{E\cap V_{\operatorname{rank}(U)+\omega}}(U\cup\{U\})$$
for transitive $U$ and $E\cap V_{\alpha+\omega}=E|\alpha+1$. Finally, we argue that the last equality holds: For $\subseteq$ note that both $E|\alpha$ and $E_\alpha$ are rudimentary in $E$ over $J_{\alpha+\omega}[E]$. Similar for $\supseteq$, $E|\alpha+1$ is rudimentary in $E|\alpha, E_\alpha$ over $\operatorname{rud}_{E|\alpha, E_\alpha}(J_\alpha[E]\cup\{J_\alpha[E]\})$.

Finally I want to mention that it is definately possible that 
$$\mathcal P(J_\alpha[E])\cap \bar\Sigma_\omega^{(J_\alpha[E],\in, E)}\subsetneq\mathcal P(J_\alpha[E])\cap J_{\alpha+\omega}[E]$$
It is a nice exercise to come up with such an example. (Hint: there are some with $\alpha=\omega$)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are somethings in your argument that I don't understand and I will try to think on them. But to get on the right track, I have a question about your last claim. Doesn't equality follow from $(*)$? Because if we let $U=J_\alpha[E]$, then everything checks out, no?

Comment: Regarding my above question, it doesn't hold because $E \not \subseteq U$, right? And I think the general theme here is that we are trying to decode $E\cap V_{\alpha + \omega}$ into subsets of $U$, so we can apply that lemma.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly right!

Comment: So I have verified some of the things in your answer for myself, but there are some points which I still don't understand. First, the strengthening you propose for $(*)$, is proven just like $(*)$ itself. But there is something that I don't understand and that is that I don't know where we use $E \subseteq U$. In the version in the handbook, they assume $E \cap V_{\operatorname{rk}(U)+\omega} \subseteq U$, which I guess is what we need, and there it is said that it is used in showing that every rud$_E$ function is simple, but when I proved it, I didn't use it. Where do we use that assumption?

Comment: Secondly, in the part that we verify the last equality, by saying e.g. "$E_\alpha$ is rudimentary in $E$" do you mean that the function $f(x) = x \cap E_\alpha$ is rud$_E$? Or do you mean that $E_\alpha$ as a relation is rud$_E$? In either case, I don't know how I can show this.

Comment: And third, I don't know where you use the amenability of $E_\alpha$. Can you please point that out?

Comment: So regarding my first question, I have come to some conclusions. First I realized that in the induction I used to prove that every rud$_E$ function is simple, I had not proved it for the case $\varphi(x) = x \in E$. When I tried to prove it, I realized I can't do it, without quantifying over $E$. So I came to this question: when defining $\Sigma_0$ formulas for structures with predicates, are we allowed to bound quantifiers with not just variables, but with terms in the language like the predicate $E$ as well? (Although in a techinal sense $E$ itself isn't a term.)

Comment: Also I guess $E\cap V_{rk(U)+\omega}\subseteq U$ is used in the end of the proof of $(*)$. Because there we use $\Sigma_0$ absoluteness between $U$ and rud$_E(U\cup\{U\})$ and if $E$ has more elements, then the predicate would be bigger and we wouldn't have absoluteness. Becuase the argument for $\Sigma_0$ absoluteness would fail in the inductive step, where we quantify over $E$, if it is allowed to do so.

Comment: And for my second question, I guess since $E_\alpha \in J_{\alpha + \omega}[E]$, we have $E_\alpha = f(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ for some rud$_E$ $f$ and $x_1, \dots, x_n \in J_\alpha[E] \cup \{J_\alpha[E]\}$. And we just have to plug this into any rud$_{E|\alpha, E_\alpha}$ function and similarly fo $E|\alpha$, which gives what we want. And the converse is similar. Did you mean something like this? Or am I confusing myself again? :)

Comment: I still have no idea about my third question.

Comment: Regarding my question on whether we can quantify over $E$ in $\Sigma_0$ formulas, as I suspected, Jensen mentiones something in his fine structure theory manuscript. He says that not all rud$_E$ functions are simple, as $\{x\}\in E$ may very well not be $\Sigma_0$. So in our case, I think we really do need to be able to quantify over $E$. Which to me seems nonstandard, but I guess there is no other way.

Comment: Also, I sincerely apologize for the walls of text that I have been commenting under your answer. I was doing so, in hopes of understanding this stuff because I am confused about it all.

Comment: No need to apologize! You raise some interesting points in your comments.  The $x\in E$ problem is a good catch. And you are completely right, if $E=\{\{a\}\}$ for some sufficiently complicated $a$ (for example $a=\omega_1$ works), then $x\mapsto\{x\}$ 
 is indeed not $E$-simple. If one only cares about proving $(\ast)$ then one needs to change the definition of simple to make things work.One way to do it is to allow quantifying over $E$. Another maybe more natural way is to allow all $\in, E$-formulas (i.e. $\varphi(f(x),...)$ can  be transformed to $\psi(x,...)$ without bounds on complexity

Comment: (continued) on both sides). Then one can see that acctually $\bar\Sigma_\omega^{(U\cup\{U\}, \in, E)}=\bar\Sigma_0^{(U\cup\{U\}, \in, E)}$ as $\exists x\varphi(x)$ is equivalent to $\exists x\in U\varphi(x)\vee\varphi(U)$ over this structure.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! That resolves about 90% of my confusion. :) As a last request, I would be very grateful if you could give a hint about where we use the amenability of $E_\alpha$.

Comment: Ah forget the fix, it doesnt work that way as you need to be able to get down from $\text{rud}_E(U\cup\{U\})$ to $U\cup\{U\}$ and this only works for $\Sigma_0$-formulas. Here is acctually the point where you use the $E\subseteq U$ assumption from $(\ast)$. You only really need that all $\text{rud}_E$-fcts are $E$-simple for $\text{rud}_E(U\cup\{U\})$ and there you can replace $\exists x\in E\varphi(x)$ by $\exists x\in U\ x\in E\wedge\varphi(x)$. 
Finally one can improve the assumption to $E\cap V_{rk(U)+\omega}\subseteq U$ by noting that in that case ...

Comment: ...(continued) $\text{rud}_E(U\cup\{U\})=\text{rud}_{E\cap U}(U\cup\{U\})$.

Comment: I think if we allow quantifications over $E$ in our $\Sigma_0$ formulas with the assumption that $E\cap V_{rk(U)+\omega}\subseteq U$, we can still prove absoluteness for $U\cup\{U\}$ and rud$_E(U\cup\{U\}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106104/discussion-between-andreas-lietz-and-shervin-sorouri).